# How to install Cuda toolkit for legacy nvidia card on Gentoo Linux

Tags: linux, cuda, nvidia, blender, gentoo

I have an old Nvidia Quadro FX 3700 graphic card using the 173.14.39 nvidia-driver, and I plan to use it for rendering with blender 2.72b on my Gentoo system (3.12.30-gentoo kernel)

I am uncertain how to install cuda for a legacy card and get it work with blender.

Do you have some hints?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/gentoo-cuda/), please google before posting question here.

Comment: Gentoo linux isn't an [officially supported Linux distro](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) for CUDA.  You can try following the [linux getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#getting-started-guides).  Your GPU probably won't be supported by CUDA toolkits after CUDA 6.5.

Answer (score 2):

The three components of CUDA can be installed using this command.

```
emerge nvidia-cuda-sdk
```

For more information check [here](http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/gentoo-cuda/).